# How to find out In App Purchase (Auto Renewable)Product price tier for all 175 territories

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

I have a live app in the App store. I am uploading Auto Renewable Products into the App Store via metadata XML by using iTMS transporter tool. I have a product price in Dollar format (ex: 0.99$) for US territory.

In XML it's mandatory to pass all 175 apple supported Territories price tier in XML.

```
My Questions are,
1. How to calculate price tier for this amount.(0.99$ USD --> Equivalent Tier).
2. Based on this, how to calculate the price tier for all other territories.

**Sample XML format:**
<prices>
 <price>
<territory>QA</territory>
**<tier>3</tier>**
</price>
<price>
<territory>AZ</territory>
**<tier>2</tier>**
</price>
<price>
<territory>SE</territory>
<tier>8</tier>
</price></prices>

I have checked App store connect API's.
```

I'm not getting the clarity on which API to use to get the price tier for all territories with respect to the given dollar amount. Can someone help me out?

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember when uploading my subscription app, I had to first create the subscription group on the developer account for the app.

The way you're doing it will charge for the app before it is installed and would a one time payment.

Create a Subscription group in the In-App Purchases section. You have to get each plan/Auto renewable subscription approved. Then use the product ID for each plan.

Two good links two help are:
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev06f89ce98
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, I have created a subscription group. I am facing a problem in price tier calculation for the given USD amount.

Comment: <in_app_purchases>
<subscription_group name="S1">
.
.
.
.
<prices>
<price>
<territory>AL</territory>
<tier>2</tier>
</price>
.. Enter price tier for 175 territories
.
.     
</prices>
<cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
</in_app_purchase>
</subscription_group>
</in_app_purchases>